# Bootstrap Fancybox Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I am choosing to use fancybox with bootstrap because I think its nicer.  Im using the bootstrap tooltip and popovers a bunch which rely on the rel option, which is setting off the fancybox gallery (left and right arrows for nav).  But, I don't want the gallery active.

I can't seem to find a simple fancybox option to disable the gallery.  My fancybox files are in the asset pipeline otherwise I'd go in and edit the code to look for something other than 'rel'...I could still easily do that but Im hoping there is a simple option.

Question:  Is there an option I can pass in the js function to disable the gallery function?  I havent found one...

Answer (score 1):

There are some suggestions in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fancybox/DQeqZoGP2ZM/discussion) in the Fancybox group that might help you out.

The simplest solution suggests setting `showNavArrows` to `false` which is, at the very least, a more maintainable solution that mimics what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on finding a js option to do this, so I just created a css override to set fancybox-nav, fancybox-next, and fancybox-prev to display:none;